# Expose an inner depedency property to the main user control

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I am working in silverlight.
Made a new UserControl called TextBoxWithButton.
Now i want add a new property to my new control called TextBoxBackground.

I did this :

```
public partial class TextBoxWithButton : UserControl
{
      public Brush TextBoxBackground
      {
           get{return textBox.Background;}
           set{textBox.Background = value;}         
      }
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to animate this property I get an exception.
I think it's because TextBoxWithButton should be defined as a dependency property but I don't know exactly how to to this.

Comment: @Snowbear3 attached property ? are you sure ? I am almost certain it's a dependency property that is capable of participating in an animation.

Comment: An attached property is just a specific type of depedency property.  Either is fine for animation, as you can animate any DP.

Comment: sure, it's `dep` property. It was a thinko from my side :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn this into a Dependency Property.  For details on implementing a DP, see [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#example_dp).

Once you have this setup as a Dependency Property, just bind your (inner) TextBox.Background to the "local" TextBoxBackground property (in xaml).  You can then animate the UserControl's TextBoxBackground property as needed, and the "inner" property will change as well.

Comment: I registered TextBoxBackground as a DP. Created the property wrapper. And in the XAML did  Background="{Binding TextBoxBackground}". But it still wont work.

Comment: @Yaron: The binding is probably not going to work unless your data context is yourself...  Otherwise, you'll need to specify the RelativeSource (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I changed the XMAL to Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=TextBoxBackground}" but still, The background of the textbox does not change